# Crash in application shutdown- issue with atexit?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, crash-dumps, atexit

one of our process is crashing during shutdown of the application. ErrorHandlingClient is a dll. I am seeing this line in the crash dump:

> "`dynamic atexit destructor for 'CErrorLog::m_IErrorHandlingServerPtr "

I searched in stack overflow as well msdn; i could not get a definite answer. Our application is ported to vc 9.0 compiler. With earlier versions this problem is not happening. Am pasting the crash dump.

```
0018fcf4  76c28681 ole32!CStdIdentity::~CStdIdentity+0x8c
0018fcf8  00000002
0018fcfc  0081aa38
0018fd00  0081a990
0018fd04  693bbf14 ErrorHandlingClient!__native_startup_lock
0018fd08  007a1890
0018fd0c  0018fd18
0018fd10  76c285eb ole32!CStdIdentity::`scalar deleting destructor'+0xd
0018fd14  0081a990
0018fd18  0018fd2c
0018fd1c  76c2882a ole32!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::Release+0x6e
0018fd20  00000001
0018fd24  005c037c
0018fd28  737d3607 msvcr90!_decode_pointer
0018fd2c  0018fd38
0018fd30  76d3b6b9 ole32!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
0018fd34  80000000
0018fd38  0018fd60
0018fd3c  693a8421 ErrorHandlingClient!`dynamic atexit destructor for 'CErrorLog::m_IErrorHandlingServerPtr''+0x11
0018fd40  0081c9ec
0018fd44  693a462f ErrorHandlingClient!_CRT_INIT+0x1be [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtdll.c @ 449]
0018fd48  693a8410 ErrorHandlingClient!`dynamic atexit destructor for 'CErrorLog::m_IErrorHandlingServerPtr''
0018fd4c  00000001
0018fd50  00000000
0018fd54  69390000 ErrorHandlingClient!Define_the_symbol__ATL_MIXED::Thank_you::Thank_you <PERF> (ErrorHandlingClient+0x0)
0018fd58  693a8410 ErrorHandlingClient!`dynamic atexit destructor for 'CErrorLog::m_IErrorHandlingServerPtr''
0018fd5c  00000000
0018fd60  0018fda4
0018fd64  693a474e ErrorHandlingClient!__DllMainCRTStartup+0xb7 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtdll.c @ 560]
```

Comment: May be this would help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952467/what-does-dynamic-in-dynamic-atexit-destructor-mean

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information but is this an issue of a COM object being destroyed after COM has been uninitialized?

m_IErrorHandlingServerPtr given its strange name is possibly a COM shared pointer which destroys when the last instance (held as a member of your class) goes out of scope, but it needs COM still alive to perform this delete.

One possible solution would be to ensure your class has its own Initialize/Uninitialize pair and this can be achieved by deriving from a base class that does the initialize in its constructor and uninitialize in its destructor. You can use private inheritance for this. You have to be careful about the different threading models.

Not sure why it wouldn't crash in older environments but they may have used COM for various things in the past that have now changed to not use COM and therefore COM happened to be alive. In addition if this is some kind of global, their destruction order is always going to be non-deterministic so essentially this will always have been undefined behaviour but in the past the "undefined" behaviour observed was that it just worked and now it doesn't.