# dynamic atexit destructor crash for inline map initialization

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a common header file which will be used in my static lib, dll and exe. Static lib is linked to my exe and dll. And Dll will be loaded by exe.
For one of the requirements, I wanted to use a global map which will be used in both dll and exe but I could not since initialization is not allowed in header(got multiple redefinition error). So I used inline feature of C++17.

In my header file, I declared a map like this.

```
enum class eCategory
{
    eInvalid = 0,
    eCategory1 = 1,
    eCategory2,
    eCategory3,
    eCategory4
};


inline std::map<eCategory, std::string> testCategoryMap{
    { eCategory::eCategory1, "Category1" },
    { eCategory::eCategory2, "Category2"},
    { eCategory::eCategory3, "Category3"},
    { eCategory::eCategory4, "Category4" },
    { eCategory::eInvalid, "Invalid" }
};
```

When I tried to execute my exe, I am getting dynamic at exit destructor crash issue. This link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952467/what-does-dynamic-in-dynamic-atexit-destructor-mean](http:///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952467/what-does-dynamic-in-dynamic-atexit-destructor-mean) suggested me to use atexit() but not sure how to implement this.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Note: I just replaced inline with static and added it inside namespace and it is working fine. Any harm in using static?

Comment: *global map which will be used in both dll and exe* -- Did you build your DLL and application using the same runtime library, and if so, is the runtime library the DLL version of the runtime?

Comment: yes. I have same settings. But I just replaced inline with static and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I just replaced inline with static and it started working.

Using `static` bypasses the application-wide One Definition Rule (ODR). The ODR instead becomes compilation-unit specific. This means you'll have multiple instances of `testCategoryMap` spread across your application, none of which interfere with one another.

Using only the `inline` keyword means the application-wide One Definition Rule does apply. Having multiple compilation units include the same header file is an ODR violation: **No diagnostic is required**. When an application has multiple compilation units that include that header, it's an undefined behavior toss-up whether or not the application builds, and if it does build, it's an undefined behavior toss-up whether or not the application crashes at some point.